# How to create a very basic health system?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a basic text adventure game in python, and am struggling with how to create a health system.  Is it possible to have an if statement constantly check for if the condition is still true, and end the code when the condition is false?  Something like

```
health = 5
if health < 0:
  game code
  #at some point the health integer drops to zero and the program ends
```

Comment: maybe an encompassing `while` loop?

Comment: another option is to perform this checking *when* health changes

Answer (score 1):

You can do the inverse, and see if a while statement breaks.  For example,

```
while health > 0:
    game works
else:
    character dies
```

You'll basically need to check the health at the beginning or end of every action.
If the health is above zero, then the program continues with its procedure.  If not, the program doesn't.

This would be a lot of processing, but most text adventures don't need to be fast.

Comment: Will I need to manually type in the code to check every action, or is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Just make it the last step inside of a for loop!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more advanced health system that is probably a bit extra than what you are going for but could help nonetheless:

```
import os
class GameStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 100
    def reduce_health(self):
        self.health = self.health - 10
        if self.health <= 0:
            game_over()

def main_game():
    game_status = GameStatus()
    #...
    # when player gets hurt
    game_status.reduce_health()
    # ...

def game_over():
    print "game over, sorry"
    os._exit(1)
```

Comment: reduce_health should probably accept an argument. Otherwise, it's a good solution.